# run a python script that takes arguments in a jupyter cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using a jupyter notebook to call an external python script

```
%run myscript.py
```

The problem is that I need to pass several arguments to `myscript` using a loop. Doing the naive

```
for myarg in ['one', 'two']:
   %run myscript.py myarg
```

does not work even though `myscript` includes:

```
import sys
myarg = sys.argv[1]
```

What is the correct way to proceed?
Thanks!

Comment: Does `myscript` actually check for arguments? You haven't given us any code for `myscript`, so I'm assuming it doesn't and you simply need to `import sys` and access with `sys.argv`. You also have a typo in `['one','two]:` that I'm guessing is not your actual code but a typo when writing out the problem here.

Comment: thanks! edited the question

Comment: Thank you for the updates. It seems to me that what you are trying should be working. Every resource I've checked for usage indicates that you can indeed pass arguments to Python scripts invoked from Jupyter Notebook this way. I'm sure you've already done this, but could you just make a simple script that simply prints `sys.argv` to see if your parameters are passing at all? Also, not sure if it matters, but Python version?

Comment: For reference, this is a resource I've found that suggests what you are doing should work. https://newbedev.com/running-a-python-script-in-jupyter-notebook-with-arguments-passing   I wouldn't think this would be an issue, but can you invoke your script with arguments without using the for loop? Just thinking of ways to debug and find the issue.

Comment: interestingly, I think using `%run`  in a loop does not work. Instead, I could run the loop using `!python myscript.py one two` but it seems that `myscript.py` is not run in my python environment because the code immediately stops and complains about a missing package (that I do have installed)